# <li> with links shows smaller bullets on iPhone

Tags: android, html, css, iphone, listitem

I noticed that `<li><a>abc</a></li>` has smaller bullets on iPhone than `<li>abc</li>`. Is there any CSS fix to this other than using background images?

Someone also told me same happens on Samsung Galaxy s5, but it looks fine on Samsung Galaxy s3.

Comment: Ask apple and they'll tell you it's a "feature". No seriously, you can't expect every small insignificant company to keep up with industry standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following code:

```
ul {
   list-style: none;
}

ul li:before {
   content: "•";
   font-size: 170%; /* or whatever */
   padding-right: 5px;
}
```

You're getting rid of the standard dot and replacing it with another that you could control the size of (adjust the font-size accordingly)

EDIT: As for why `<li>abc</li>` might be bigger than `<li><a>abc</a></li>`, it could be because your  tag could have styles that's being applied as well and ultimately it would affect the size of your content.

That or the fact that `<a></a>` isn't properly used and could be causing you problems.